# Не запускается приложение после компиляции

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Я скомпилировал приложение с помощью команды pyinstaller --onefile send.py  , а так-же пробовал pyinstaller -F send.py , однако после запуска получившегося .exe файла открывается консоль, немного висит и резко закрывается выдавая, что-то не понятное, далее я пробовал открыть это приложение через cmd, вот что пишет

```
    Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'C:\Users\805B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI82802'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Users\\u0410\u0440\u0441\u043b\u0430\u043d\OneDrive\\u0420\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0447\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u0442\u043e\u043b\\u041a \u0441\u0431\u043e\u0440\u043a\u0435\send.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 0
  user site = 0
  import site = 0
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\\u0410\u0440\u0441\u043b\u0430\u043d\\OneDrive\\\u0420\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0447\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u0442\u043e\u043b\\\u041a \u0441\u0431\u043e\u0440\u043a\u0435\\send.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = ''
  sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\\u0410\u0440\u0441\u043b\u0430\u043d\\OneDrive\\\u0420\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0447\u0438\u0439 \u0441\u0442\u043e\u043b\\\u041a \u0441\u0431\u043e\u0440\u043a\u0435\\send.exe'
  sys.prefix = ''
  sys.exec_prefix = ''
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\805B~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI82802\\base_library.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\805B~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI82802\\lib-dynload',
    'C:\\Users\\805B~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI82802',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
LookupError: unknown encoding: utf-8

Current thread 0x00002064 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Переменные в "Системные переменные" имеются, там переменная PATH и в ней прописано следующее -
C:\Python
C:\Python\Scripts\

Версия pyinstaller 4.3
Версия python 3.9.5 32-bit
Версия pip 21.1.2

Comment: Попробуйте переместить проект в папку, на пути к которой не было бы русских букв. У Вас, как минимум, имя пользователя на русском.

Comment: Попробовал, точно так-же. У меня сам скрип .py работает, а скомпилированный .exe нет

Comment: вывело это :
https://pastebin.com/8zCEkTrk , то-есть тоже самое

Comment: У Вас PYTHONPATH не установлен

Comment: Погуглив, нашёл вот что (перевод): "Это не ошибка Python, это симптом установки PYTHONHOME и / или PYTHONPATH, когда они не нужны. Почти во всех случаях вам не нужно устанавливать ни один из них; в случае PYTHONHOME установка почти всегда является ошибкой.

Есть ли особая причина, по которой вы пытаетесь установить эти переменные? Вы следуете руководству, которое предлагает это?" То есть, возможно, как раз и не нужно устанавливать ни одну из этих переменных.

Comment: @V-Mor я видел этот результат в поисковике, я не понимаю, что с этим делать, убрать путь к Python и Python/Scripts ?

Comment: интерфейс есть в приложении? если да уточните не  pyQT используете?

Comment: @Sky Интерфейса нету, классический python с модулями загруженные с помощью pip`a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл лично моё решение, взял его отсюда https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5438 -> This seems to be due to typing package installed under python version where it is not necessary anymore. Uninstalling typing should fix the problem. See psf/black#1707 (comment) and the corresponding typing issue that's linked there (i.e., python/typing#573).

Нужно было просто удалить модуль typing , я незнаю за что он отвечает, но у меня приложение заработало после этого

pip uninstall typing